# How do i get rid of free-jqgrid's right-side scrollbar space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm upgrading jqgrid to the latest stable build of free-jqgrid (4.15.2) and the grid always shows a right-side gap where the scollbar will never need to be. It appears as though some of the usage has changed since the last developer updated the library and might be ahead of the documentation. I've looked at other questions in SO and:

- I've tried manually stylling the grid, which did not help and served only to complicate matters.
- I've tried setting `scrollOffset:0` (with and without a height set in both percentatge and a static int) and it has not removed the scrollbar area

Other helpful info:
  *  We're manually resizing the grid to it's container on resize event and on initial draw. This code seems to have little effect now

I'm seeing the unsightly gap every time i set up a grid in a similar fashion to the following:

```
var grid_data = {
                altRows: true,
                data: [],
                datatype: 'local',
                sortable: false,
                width: (bodyWidth() - 14),
                rowNum: 10000,
                colNames: [],
                ondblClickRow: function() {
                    onGridDblClickRow();
                },
                onSelectAll: function() {
                    onGridSelectAll();
                },
                gridComplete: function() {
                    doGridComplete();
                    }
                },
                onRightClickRow: function( rowId ) {
                    doRightClick(rowId);
                    }
                },
                onSelectRow: $.proxy( onGridSelectRow, this ),
                colModel: column_info_array,
                multiselect: true,
                multiselectWidth: 22,
                viewrecords: true,
                height:'100%',
                scrollOffset:0,
            }
```

The following fiddle shows the same problem in more reduced code
http://jsfiddle.net/catbadger/mhvzerdg/8/

Comment: Could you post **the demo** (as JSFiddle, for example), which reproduce the problem? The code like `colModel: column_info_array`, `gridComplete: function() { doGridComplete(); }` gives practically no information. Moreover it's unclear how you fill the data in the grid. One creates typically the grid with data. I suppose that the origin of your problem inside of `doGridComplete` or in the way how you fill the grid. By the way, the latest version of free jqGrid is 4.15.2.

Comment: The fiddle has been added to the question. thank you for your prompt response, @Oleg!

Comment: The demo has no jQuery CSS or Bootstrap CSS and it has no data. What you expect to see? Look at [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for some simple examples.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. there's no need for bootstrap css. the gap is there between the border of the containing div and the grid.

Comment: The grid still has no data. The right space in the column header is the part of `<div id="outer_div">`. You use very strange value of `width` option: `width: ( $('body').width() - 14 )` which reserves 14px on the right side of the grid. If you change to `autowidth: true` or `width: $("#outer_div").width()` then I see no problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/mhvzerdg/9/. I repeat that the *filling* of grid with data could be your problem. Thus it's important that the demo will be with the data. I see additional many unneeded options and strange code fragments like `this.setGridSize`.

Comment: You're right. i failed to replicate the bug here. I'll go over it again and see if i can figure it out.